# wordpress site comments section are not displaying

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have migrated my website & using Avada theme.
I can see my comment section isn't showing.It shows comments are closed though I have allow comment from the discussion area.

Answer (score 0):

In the Admin area of your site, click on "Settings" (on the far right). That should bring up the "General Settings" page.

In the "Membership" row, make sure that the following is checked:
"Anyone can register" (unless you want to manually add users, say friends and family).

And that "Users must be registered and logged in to comment" is unchecked. I think that's the option that's blocking the comment form in your case.